# Generic detail view ProfileView must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django 2.0 and i'm getting this error when visiting my profile page view. It's working with urls like `path('users/<int:id>')` but i wanted to urls be like `path('<username>')`. Not sure what exactly is the problem. I hope you can help.

```
#views.py
class ProfileView(views.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.User
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'


#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('signup', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout', logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('<username>', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
]


#base.html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:profile' user.username %}">View Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user has a `username`? Does `{% url 'accounts:profile' "bob" %}` work?

Answer (score 12):

You need to tell your view to use `username` as the lookup field. You could either do this by defining `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` on the model, or by overriding `get_object`. For example:

```
class ProfileView(views.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.User
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

The first of these determines what field to use in the model lookup; the second determines what variable to use from the URL pattern.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers.

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't simply change your path to:

```
url('(?P<username>[\w]+)', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
```

And then in your html do this:

```
{% url 'accounts:profile' username=user.username %}
```

Another way would be to do this:

```
url('accounts/profile', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
```

And in your profile template use request.user to access you user data

EDIT:

Try to override the `get_object` method as explained [here](https://chriskief.com/2012/12/29/django-generic-detailview-without-a-pk-or-slug/)

```
def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.session['user_id'])
```

Comment: This does not in any way answer the question. Plus, `path` does not accept a regex.

Comment: Thanks for answering but it shows still same error :(

Comment: i used `re_path` btw