# Django detailview get_queryset and get_object

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-generic-views

I am using Django detailview. initially, I used the URL pattern

```
url(r'^todo/details/(?P<pk>[\d]+)', views.todoDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_todo'),
```

my view is

```
class todoDetailView(DetailView):
model = models.todo
```

It worked fine.

In the second case, my URL is

```
url(r'^todo/details/(?P<id>[\d]+)', views.todoDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_todo'),
```

this time, I modified my view to

```
class todoDetailView(DetailView):
model = models.todo
# context_object_name = 'todo_detail'

 def get_object(self, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    return models.todo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
```

It worked fine, I modified the second case to

```
class todoDetailView(DetailView):
model = models.todo
# context_object_name = 'todo_detail'

def get_queryset(self):
    return models.todo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
```

then I get an error,

> Generic detail view todoDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

I know that there is no proper slug or pk provided. So, initially I added get_object() (it worked) but get_queryset() is not working. What is the difference in their working ??

And also if a user is getting details only based on the slug, I read on StackOverflow that

this can be used

```
slug_field = 'param_name'
slug_url_kwarg = 'param_name'
```

link - [Generic detail view ProfileView must be called with either an object pk or a slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497771/generic-detail-view-profileview-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-pk-or-a-slu)

Can anyone explain me actual working of get_object() and get_queryset() (also get_slug_field() if possible)

Along with the terms `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is the difference between these two views?

Comment: Unrelated observation: according to the PEP8 style guide, class names should use the CapWords convention (i.e. the first letter should also be capitalized). So your `todoDetailView` should be `TodoDetailView`.

Comment: Thanks @Ariel will update it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`get_object` returns an object (an instance of your model), while `get_queryset` returns a QuerySet object mapping to a set of potentially multiple instances of your model. In the case of the `DetailView` (or in fact any class that inherits from the `SingleObjectMixin`, the purpose of the `get_queryset` is to [restrict the set of objects from which you'll try to fetch your instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset).

If you want to show details of an instance, you have to somehow tell Django how to fetch that instance. By default, as the error message indicates, Django calls the `get_object` method which looks for a `pk` or `slug` parameter in the URL. In your first example, where you had `pk` in the URL, Django managed to fetch your instance automatically, so everything worked fine. In your second example, you overrode the `get_object` method and manually used the `id` passed as parameter to fetch the object, which also worked. In the third example, however, you didn't provide a `get_object` method, so Django executed the default one. SingleObjectMixin's default `get_object` method didn't find either a pk or a slug, so it failed.

There are multiple ways to fix it:

## 1. Use `pk` in the URL

The simplest one is to simply use the code you provided in your first example. I don't know why you were unsatisfied with that, it is perfectly fine. If you're not happy, please explain why in more detail.

## 2. Override `get_object`

This is the second solution you provided. It is overkill because if you properly configured your view with the correct options (as you will see in the following alternatives), Django would take care of fetching the object for you.

## 3. Provide the `pk_url_kwarg` option

If you really want to use `id` in the URL for some reason, you can indicate that in your view by specifying the `pk_url_kwarg` option:

```
class todoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.todo
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

## 4. Provide the `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` options [DON'T DO THIS]

This is a terrible solution because you are not really using a slug, but an id, but it should in theory work. You will basically "fool" Django into using the `id` field as if it was a slug. I am only mentioning it because you explicitly asked about these options in your question.

```
class todoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.todo
    slug_field = 'id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

Regarding your `get_queryset` method: in your example, it doesn't even get to be executed, but in any case it is broken because it returns an individual object instead of a queryset (that's what `objects.get` does). My guess is you probably don't need a custom `get_queryset` method at all. This would be useful for example if you had a complex permission system in which different users can only access a different subset of `todo` objects, which I assume is not your case. Currently, if you provide this `get_queryset` method, even if everything else is configured properly, you will get an error. Probably an AttributeError saying that the `queryset` object has no attribute `filter` (because it will actually be a `todo` object and not a QuerySet object [as Django expects](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L36)).

Answer (score 2):

The default `get_object` for `DetailView` tries to fetch the object using `pk` or `slug` from the URL. The simplest thing for you to do is to use `(?P<pk>[\d]+)` in the URL pattern.

When you override `get_object`, you are replacing this default behaviour, so you don't get any errors.

When you override `get_queryset`, Django first runs your `get_queryset` method an fetches the queryset. It then tries to fetch the object from that queryset using `pk` or `slug`, and you get an error because you are not using either of them.

The [`slug_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_field) and [`slug_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.slug_url_kwarg) parameters are both defined in the docs. The `slug_fields` is the name of the field in the model used to fetch the item, and `slug_url_kwarg` is the name of the parameter in the URL pattern. In your case, you are fetching the object using the primary key (`pk`/`id`), so you shouldn't use either of these options.

For your URL pattern with `(?P<id>[\d]+)`, you could use `pk_url_kwarg = 'id'`. That would tell Django to fetch the object using `id` from the URL. However, it's much simpler to use your first URL pattern with `(?P<pk>[\d]+)`, then you don't have to override any of the methods/attributes above.

Answer (score 1):

get_object() majorly uses with the generic views which takes pk or id

like: `DetailView`, `UpdateView`, `DeleteView`

where get_queryset() uses with the `ListView` where we are expecting more objects

Also, `get_object()` or `self.get_object()` uses pk as default lookup field or can use slug Field

a little peek at `get_object()`

```
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

    # Next, try looking up by primary key.
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
    if pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

    # Next, try looking up by slug.
    if slug is not None and (pk is None or self.query_pk_and_slug):
        slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with what the error message explicitly means, but `get_queryset` is used in listviews by get multiple objects, while `get_object` is used to get a single object (ie `DetailView`).

If you have a pk you can use to get an object, you don't need to specify a slug field. Slug field are used to filter out objects when you don't have or can't show the primary key publicly. [This gives a better explanation of a slug field.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django)